# Block IP Address using php

Tags: php, ip-address

For my website i use this php code to block ip addresses.

```
<?php
$deny = array("111.111.111", "222.222.222", "333.333.333");
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
   header("location: http://www.google.com/");
   exit();
} ?>
```

How to re-edit this code to block ip addresses like all addresses starting from "111."  or "222." like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use regex in here.

Comment: is it possible through php?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
<?
$deny = array("111.111.111", "222.222.222", "333.333.333");
foreach ($deny as $denyip) {
  if (strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $denyip)===0) {
    header("location: http://www.google.com/");
    exit();
  } 
}
?>
```

This basically loops through all denied IP's and checks if the user's IP starts with the IP written in the deny list. It will also work if you put full ip in the deny list, so you can combine full and partial ip's.

Notice the `===` in comparison. It means that the position must really be `0`, which means that user IP begins with the ip in the deny list. If you only put `==` it will block all users who are not found in the deny list too, since `false==0` in php, so that is why you must use `===` instead.